# Script running in console window but not in tempmonkey

Tags: html, console

This is the script I wrote on tempmonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Script2
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-02-03
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://ww8.soap2dayhd.co/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Find the video player element using the selector
    document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2;
})();
```

and it is not working

but when I run :

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2;
```

in console window then it is working perfectly fine
Why ??????????????